# Why doesnt steel melt when pouring titanium through it

Tags: finite-element-method

How come you can pour molten titanium with a melting point of 3291 degrees into a steel funnel with a melting point of 1300 degrees and it doesn't melt the funnel?

Comment: At the very least, provide source citations for your claims.

Comment: How come when I put water in a saucepan at 200 degrees C, when water has a boiling point of 100 degrees C, the water doesn't all instantly evaporate?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly you're mixing units

The melting point of titanium is 1668C (3000F)

The melting point of steel starts at around 1300C up to around 1500C depending on carbon content.

For brief contact where the mass of the steel is reasonably high you would probably get away with this but generally foundry equipment which comes into contact with molten metal is lined with a refractory of some sort. Which both provides thermal insulation and prevents cross-contamination.

Rather more of an issue is the reactivity of titanium which will burn in air some time before it gets to its melting point and needs inert gas shielding to be worked hot.

Comment: Molten titanium requires noble gas , eg He , Ar,  or vacuum protection to be poured. It reacts with  O , N , H , etc.